# Swift Closures - How to pass a parameter and have no return value

Tags: ios, swift, closures

In the following code, I’m trying to create a closure that is passed a single parameter that will be used in the closure, where no value is returned:

The code is called from another Swift class in my app via `runit()`

> Cannot invoke value of type ‘(CheckerOperation) -> ()’ with argument
>   list ‘(CheckerOperation)’ at the line
>   “runTimerProcess(runitProcess(customOperation))

I don’t understand how to invoke when the closure will not be returning a value.

(`CheckerOperation` is just a custom `NSOperation` class)

```
class Checker {
  var queue = NSOperationQueue()
  let customOperation : CheckerOperation = CheckerOperation()

  var runitProcess: (CheckerOperation) -> () = {op in
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
        let operationQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
        operationQueue.addOperation(op)
    })
  }

  func runTimerProcess(closureblock: ClosureBlock){
    let queue = dispatch_queue_create(“myqueue”, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
    dispatch_async(queue,closureblock)
  }

  func runit(){
     runTimerProcess(runitProcess(customOperation))
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, in order to help you, can you post your code for `ClosureBlock`and `CheckerOperation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing two core syntaxes: (1) **computed properties**, and (2) **functions/methods**.

Computed properties cannot accept arguments. For your case, you should be simply defining a function with an argument `op` with a type of `CheckerOperation`. I say this because you don't appear to need to return or check a value on `runitProcess` which is really what a computed property is intended for.

Use this:

```
func runitProcess(op: CheckerOperation) {
    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
        let operationQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
        operationQueue.addOperation(op)
}
```